# Increasing a number when another number gets smaller than 0

Tags: functions

This should be trivial but for some reason I cannot think of a formula which enlarges a number in proportion to another number decreasing in the negative direction

Example:

if value 1 = $-0.1$, value 2 should be set to $0.9$
if value 1 = $-0.2$, value 2 should be set to $0.8$
if value 1 = $-0.4$, value 2 should be set to $0.6$

and so on...

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about $$\mathsf{(\text{value 2})}=1+\mathsf{(\text{value 1})}\quad ?$$
It fits all the examples you gave.

Comment: Thought it was something simple which I wasn't thinking about! Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In your description you mention that one should be increasing while the other is decreasing. In your examples, both value1 and value2 are getting smaller.